# nftw thread safe

Tags: c, recursion, thread-safety, delete-file, nftw

Is there any thread safe implementation of [nftw()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html) in C/C++? In the documentation it says

> "The nftw() function need not be thread-safe."

I'm going to use nftw for a recursive delete function to walk through the directory structure in a multi threaded application.

Comment: You're probably not going to get any speedup anyway because walking the directory tree is I/O bound.

Comment: OP did not say he/she wants a multi-threaded `nftw` or to perform multiple directory tree walks in different threads for performance purposes. The problem is that, per the specification, `nftw` is not safe for multi-threaded use, so if the application is multi-threaded, one must make special (often prohibitively costly) efforts to ensure that it's not possible to invoke it in more than one thread at once.

Comment: Does anyone know why nftw is not thread safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One trivial way to make a non-thread-safe function thread-safe is to wrap it in a function that obtains a lock before calling it, and always call it through this wrapper. In general you would need to copy out the results before unlocking, but `nftw` does not yield any results that would need to be copied after it returns. A few caveats though:

1. This will of course prevent all parallelism when multiple threads want to use the interface.
2. One option to `nftw` makes it `chdir` to each directory it walks. This is a very bad thing for a multi-threaded app (since the current directory is shared by all threads), so you should avoid using this option.

On POSIX 2008 systems with the `openat` and related interfaces, it's pretty trivial to implement your own equivalent of `nftw` without any `chdir` usage or pathname length limitations, so you might be better off just writing your own.

Comment: +1 ha, I didn't consider the possibility that the OP might just be after correctness rather than performance.

Comment: ..and of course, even more trivial is to ensure that your code only calls `nftw()` from a single thread.  You can also use `chdir()` if you treat the current working directory as a resource in its own right, and protect it by a mutex.

Comment: @caf: If you `chdir`, then any use of relative pathnames in your program must be done under lock. I would rather treat the current working directory as a constant, the directory in which the program was initially invoked, or do away with it entirely by `chdir('/')` in long-lived programs where you don't want to possibly prevent unmounting a filesystem.

Comment: @caf: And I think you overestimate the "triviality" of ensuring `nftw` is only called from a single thread. If you have a gui program where each window runs in a thread, or a server where each connection runs in a thread, it's natural for them to perform their own operations, and unnatural for them to have to worry about what other threads are doing when they're not actually working with shared data.